# Android ZXING encode qr via BitMatrix --> store to byte[] --> insert to database

Tags: android, zxing, bytebuffer

I have been playing around with zxing over the weekend, and have ran into a problem that I am unable to solve.  I am using the working java code example at [QR Code encoding and decoding using zxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489048/qr-code-encoding-and-decoding-using-zxing), and am interested in converting the generated BitMatrix (that houses bits of the qr code) into a byte[] so that I can store the image in an sql lite blob field (and then draw the bar code when I want to).  Does anyone know if this is possible.  I am not sure where to go from the encoding solution that I have provided.  I've looked at http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/client/j2se/MatrixToImageWriter.html for a solution, but haven't found any fixes for my problem (I thought maybe accomplish this via MatrixToImageWriter.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BitMatrix](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/common/BitMatrix.java) has several methods to get its contents, like `get()` which gets bit by bit or `getRow()` which gives you a row at a time as a `BitArray`. You can get the bits and do whatever you want.

Comment: so the idea would be to loop through the BitMatrix, continually adding the rows to the byte[]?  Then I could toss this into the database base blob field?

Comment: Yeah exactly just read off the the bits row by row and build your byte array from those bits. You can do the reverse to reconstruct the matrix.

Comment: Hey Sean, I seem to be running into another problem.  Maybe you can spot it if you're around.

Comment: What is the question? The Google Group for the project is probably a better place to continue.

Comment: I figured it out :).  It was a slight error in the decoding process that I caught.  I'll go ahead and mark this as the best answer.  Thanks for your help, Sean!

Comment: @SeanOwen is there an example of getting a `byte[]` from `BitMatrix`, or has this API changed? I'm also trying to get `byte[]` from `BitMatrix` and not seeing a clear way