# Can Barcode4j run in Android?

Tags: android, barcode

I have to make an app that takes strings and makes barcodes in different barcode formats.

I found Barcode4j. Looks like a library that fits my needs, but I also found people that says that it doesn't works on Android.

Is this the best library for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zebra Crossing:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

is the go to barcode library for android. Even Google uses it :-)

Comment: But that's a scanner. Can I stay only with the encoding part? Thanks

Comment: Sure can, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489048/qr-code-encoding-and-decoding-using-zxing

Comment: @Hugo not without heavy modifications, I believe. But it seems those necessary modifications have been done once, as seen in this Barcode4J fork, at least: https://github.com/dingram/barcode4android