# How to scan QRCode in android

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I found [a tutorial](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent) on how to scan a barcode. But in my application I have to scan a QR code. How can I a scan QR code in Android?

Comment: Zxing also scans QR code:
see their main page [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Comment: There is a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489048/qr-code-encoding-and-decoding-using-zxing

ZXing works well on QR codes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I missed to read the document of Zxing

Comment: You could use [NEO reader](http://www.neom.com/solutions/neoreader/SDK) also.

Comment: @IshitaSinha I have used zbar scanner (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) now-a-days. Its awesome

Comment: Please refer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080181/qr-code-reading-with-camera-android I think this will help you out

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); // "PRODUCT_MODE for bar codes

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
} catch (Exception e) {    
    Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,marketUri);
    startActivity(marketIntent);
}
```

and in `onActivityResult():`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        }
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELLED){
            //handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to scan the qrcode from my project without installing any other scanners.is it possible?please give your suggestion.

Comment: @sandhya.M yeah there is a way. You have to download Zxing's source code. Its open source. Generate core.jar file and add it as external jar.

Comment: only core.jar file is enough.or any other source files also i have to add it

Comment: No it can be compiled with only core.jar

Comment: i have done like that only.but iam not able to scan the qrcode.

Comment: Did you generate core.jar on your own?

Comment: no.i have downloaded the Zxing-2.0 in that from core folder i have copied the core.jar and i added to the my project by configre build path

Comment: can u tell how to generate that.plaese.iam trying for this from twodays onwards

Comment: here are steps to generate core.jar.  http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: can u please explain that step by step procedure to scan the qrcode from my app

Comment: You first need to install apache ant

Comment: and then run it in the core folder

Comment: k.thank u i will look at that document and i will try.if i got any doubts i will ask.please help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12690/discussion-between-seshu-vinay-and-sandhya-m)

Comment: Zxing's code means for scanning Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); 
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE"); 
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
 is it this only

Comment: Hi, I have tried with the above code working fine but ads are coming.How to disable ads in Android ?

Answer (score 16):

### 2016 update

The current recommendation is to use the [Android Barcode API](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview), which works [locally](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html) (offline), [without](https://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/bar-codes) requiring a server roundtrip:

> The Barcode API detects barcodes in real-time, on device, in any orientation. It can also detect multiple barcodes at once.
>
> It reads the following barcode formats:
>
> - 1D barcodes: EAN-13, EAN-8, UPC-A, UPC-E, Code-39, Code-93, Code-128, ITF, Codabar
> - 2D barcodes: QR Code, Data Matrix, PDF-417, AZTEC
>
> It automatically parses QR Codes, Data Matrix, PDF-417, and Aztec values, for the following supported formats:
>
> - URL
> - Contact information (VCARD, etc.)
> - Calendar event
> - Email
> - Phone
> - SMS
> - ISBN
> - WiFi
> - Geo-location (latitude and longitude)
> - AAMVA driver license/ID

Check out the codelab - [Barcode Detection with the Mobile Vision API](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/barcodes/).

Answer (score 12):

You can scan QR code easily with `zxing`  add the following dependencies in your gradle

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
```

Then in your `Activity` or on `Fragment`

```
   IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(context);
                scanIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                scanIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
                //The following line if you want QR code
                scanIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                scanIntegrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivityAnyOrientation.class);
                scanIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
                scanIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
```

And then capture the result in `onActivityResult`

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            if (scanningResult.getContents() != null) {
                scanContent = scanningResult.getContents().toString();
                scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName().toString();
            }

            Toast.makeText(this,scanContent+"   type:"+scanFormat,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Nothing scanned",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Take a look at this [sample project](https://github.com/sshuvro58/BarCodeScanner)  , hope it helps you .

Comment: what is CaptureActivityAnyOrientation?

Answer (score 7):

One way is using the AppCompatActivity and ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler interface.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.example.team.merchant.functional.Request;
import com.example.team.merchant.functional.ResponseListener;
import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

/**
 * Created by Prakhar on 5/16/2016.
 */
public class MerchantScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(60, 60);
        params.setMargins(0, 50, 50, 0);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);


        Button switchCamera = new Button(this); //declare a button in layout for camera change option
        switchCamera.setLayoutParams(params);
        switchCamera.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.switch_camera);
        relativeLayout.addView(switchCamera);
        final int i = getFrontCameraId();
        if (i == -1) {
            switchCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        relativeLayout.addView(mScannerView);

        setContentView(relativeLayout);
        final int[] id = {0};
        switchCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mScannerView.stopCamera();
                if (id[0] % 2 == 0) {
                    mScannerView.startCamera(i);
                } else {
                    mScannerView.startCamera();
                }
                id[0]++;
            }
        });

        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);// Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.

        mScannerView.startCamera();         // Start camera


    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    int getFrontCameraId() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) {
            Camera.CameraInfo ci = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
                Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
                if (ci.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) return i;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                CameraManager cManager = (CameraManager) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                String[] cameraId = cManager.getCameraIdList();
                for (int j = 0; j < cameraId.length; j++) {
                    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId[j]);
                    int cOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                    if (cOrientation == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
                        return Integer.parseInt(cameraId[j]);
                }
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return -1; // No front-facing camera found
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
       // rawResult.getText()
       // handle your result here
       // handle exceptions here
    }
}
```

Other can be used in fragments accordingly.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.zxing.ResultPoint;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeCallback;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeResult;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView;


/**
 * Created by Prakhar on 3/8/2016.
 */
public class PayWithQrCodeScannerFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA = 23;
    public static CompoundBarcodeView barcodeScannerView;
    public static BarcodeCallback callback;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.paywithqrcodescannerfragment, container, false);

        barcodeScannerView = (CompoundBarcodeView) view.findViewById(R.id.zxing_barcode_scanner);


        callback = new BarcodeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
                    // handle result and exceptions here
            }
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the device's camera has a Flashlight.
     *
     * @return true if there is Flashlight, otherwise false.
     */
    private boolean hasFlash() {
        return getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            barcodeScannerView.resume();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            barcodeScannerView.pause();
        }
    }

}
```

Use below written in layout XML file to placeholder the scanner

```
<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
            android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_scanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:zxing_preview_scaling_strategy="centerCrop"
            app:zxing_use_texture_view="false" />
```

Build.gradle

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

My way is to use [`barcodescanner`](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner). I uses [`zxing`](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) for scanning bar codes and QR codes. The version `1.9` of the library utilises `zxing v3.2.1`. It's a wrapper for `zxing` so the usage is simplier.

In order to do this:

1. Add dependency to gradle

   ```
   compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
   ```
2. Add camera permission to manifest

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
   ```
3. Create activity, that will handle scanning

   **Manifest:**

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".view.component.ScannerActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:theme="@style/AppThemeTransparent"/>
   ```

   **styles.xml:**

   ```
   <style name="AppThemeTransparent" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
   </style>
   ```

   **Create scanner activity:**

   ```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.WindowManager;

   import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
   import com.google.zxing.Result;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Collection;
   import java.util.List;

   import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

   public class ScannerActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

       public static final String EXCLUDED_FORMAT = "ExcludedFormat";
       private static final String TAG = ScannerActivity.class.getSimpleName();
       private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
           setStatusBarTranslucent(true);
           super.onCreate(state);
           mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
           setContentView(mScannerView);
       }

       protected void setStatusBarTranslucent(boolean makeTranslucent) {
           if (makeTranslucent) {
               getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
           } else {
               getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onResume() {
           super.onResume();
           mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
           mScannerView.startCamera();
       }

       @Override
       public void onPause() {
           super.onPause();
           mScannerView.stopCamera();
       }

       @Override
       public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
           String result = rawResult.getText();
           BarcodeFormat format = rawResult.getBarcodeFormat();

           Log.v(TAG, "Scanned code: " + rawResult.getText());
           Log.v(TAG, "Scanend code type: " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

           //Return error
           if (result == null) {
               setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnErrorCode(result, format));
               finish();
           }

           if (result.isEmpty()) {
               setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnErrorCode(result, format));
               finish();
           }

           //Return correct code
           setResult(RESULT_OK, returnCorrectCode(result, format));
           finish();
       }

       private Intent returnErrorCode(String result, BarcodeFormat format) {
           Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
           returnIntent.putExtra(ScannerConstants.ERROR_INFO, getResources().getString(R.string.scanner_error_message));
           return returnIntent;
       }

       private Intent returnCorrectCode(String result, BarcodeFormat format) {
           Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
           returnIntent.putExtra(ScannerConstants.SCAN_RESULT, result);

           if (format.equals(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE)) {
               returnIntent.putExtra(ScannerConstants.SCAN_RESULT_TYPE, ScannerConstants.QR_SCAN);
           } else {
               returnIntent.putExtra(ScannerConstants.SCAN_RESULT_TYPE, ScannerConstants.BAR_SCAN);
           }

           return returnIntent;
       }

       public void excludeFormats(BarcodeFormat item) {
           Collection<BarcodeFormat> defaultFormats = mScannerView.getFormats();
           List<BarcodeFormat> formats = new ArrayList<>();
           for (BarcodeFormat format : defaultFormats) {
               if (!format.equals(item)) {
                   formats.add(format);
               }
           }
           mScannerView.setFormats(formats);
       }

       public interface ScannerConstants {
           public static final String SCAN_MODES = "SCAN_MODES";
           public static final String SCAN_RESULT = "SCAN_RESULT";
           public static final String SCAN_RESULT_TYPE = "SCAN_RESULT_TYPE";
           public static final String ERROR_INFO = "ERROR_INFO";
           public static final int BAR_SCAN = 0;
           public static final int QR_SCAN = 1;
       }
   }
   ```

   Just be sure, that on API 23+ devices a permission for camera usage is granted for the application.

   Open the `Activity` just like the normal one with result expectation:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(AddEquipmentActivity.this, ScannerActivity.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_SERIAL_REQUEST);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `function` that scans the QR Code.

```
public void scanQR(View v)
{
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe)
    {
        showDialog(ActivityUserDetails.this, "No Scanner Found",
                "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, I have invoked `showDialog()` method from `catch` block, that will show an `AlertDialog` for asking to install "Barcode Scanner" app from Google Play. Given below is the code for `showDialog` method.

```
private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity act,
                                      CharSequence title, CharSequence message, CharSequence buttonYes,
                                      CharSequence buttonNo)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
    downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:"
                            + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    try
                    {
                        act.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe)
                    {

                    }
                }
            });
            downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {
                }
            });
            return downloadDialog.show();
}
```

I have used this function on `Button` click event. Therefore the code for `Button` is given below (xml file).

```
                    <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_wr_scan"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_shadow"
                    android:onClick="scanQR"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"
                    android:text="ScanQR" />
```

**NOTE**: The prerequisite for using this function is that you must have pre installed "Barcode Scanner" app in your device.

Hope it helps.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**Step by step to setup zxing 3.2.1 in eclipse**

1. Download zxing-master.zip from "https://github.com/zxing/zxing"
2. Unzip zxing-master.zip, Use eclipse to import "android" project in zxing-master
3. Download core-3.2.1.jar from "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.2.1/"
4. Create "libs" folder in "android" project and paste cor-3.2.1.jar into the libs folder
5. Click on project: choose "properties" -> "Java Compiler" to change level to 1.7. Then click on "Android" change "Project build target" to android 4.4.2+, because using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4
6. If "CameraConfigurationUtils.java" don't exist in "zxing-master/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/". You can copy it from "zxing-master/android-core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/" and paste to your project.
7. Clean and build project. If your project show error about "switch - case", you should change them to "if - else".
8. Completed. Clean and build project
   Reference link: [How to use Zxing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708705/how-to-use-zxing-in-android/33536249#33536249)

Answer (score 0):

module gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0'
}
```

activity.kt

```
package com.example.qrcode

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import com.google.android.material.internal.ContextUtils.getActivity
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult

class LicenseCheck : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.licensecheck)
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

        fun checklicense(license: String){
            Toast.makeText(this, license, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        val scanbtn = findViewById(R.id.qrscanner) as ImageButton
        scanbtn.setOnClickListener {
            val integrator = IntentIntegrator(this)
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE)
            integrator.setPrompt("Focus QRCode from App...")
            integrator.setCameraId(0)
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(true)
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false)
            integrator.initiateScan()
        }
        @Override
        fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data: Intent) {
            var result: IntentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                checklicense(result.getContents());
            }
        }
    }
}
```