# I'm trying to scan qr code and open multiple websites in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, qr-code

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
                               Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                               Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

I have tried this but it is redirecting to only google page, but my requirement is to open different webpages. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: So your question really is "how do I scan a qr and put the result inside a string"?

Comment: If that's the case, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080181/qr-code-reading-with-camera-android)