# BarcodeScanner result not displaying

Tags: java, android, fragment, barcode, zxing

I'm doing a code which has fragments and one of the fragment job is to scan a barcode and display the contents but currently it won't display anything

I debugged and the `activityResult` is not being called at all

Here is the code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class PriceFragment extends Fragment{
    public PriceFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    Button scan_btn;
    TextView barcode;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_price, container, false);
        scan_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        //initialize the textViews
        barcode = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.barcodeResult);
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            barcode.setText(result.getContents());
        }else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I never work with zxing, but generally, if you want to catch on activity result in your fragment you need to call... `fragment.startActivityForResult(...)`. `IntentIntegrator()`... probably don't do this cause you give im your activity.

You can try to:

1. can you give im your fragment?
2. if you override onActivityForResult. on the activity who contain your fragment will it work?

But I will suggest that you use [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#0) google's library for barcode reader.

Comment: alright bubt the tricky part is putting it into a fragment......but can i actually link a activity which not a fragment to a fragment? sorry still new to all these java and android

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.html) You are doing almost everything properly. However, there is one more thing needed:

> your Activity must implement the method Activity.onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)

You are initialising `IntentIntegrator` with your `Activity`:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
```

The result is passed to the `Activity` and not the `Fragment`. All you need to do is pass the result to the appropriate `Fragment`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28577980/6507689).

Be aware, that the method you are using requires existance of the external application installed on the phone that can handle such `Intent` (as the documentation states). If you would like to handle scanning inside your app internally, use [barcodescanner] (https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) library. The usage is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39656445/6507689)

Comment: Activity as in MainActivity?

Comment: I don't know, how your `Activity` is called. But it must be the one, where `Fragment` is put inside.