# Encoding and decoding byte[] with ZXing

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, zxing, iso-8859-1

I am developping an Android app, and I need to encode and decode a bytes array in a QRCode generated with the ZXing app. My problem is that my message decoded does not exactly match the generated byte array.
I tried to create a QRCode based on a byte array containing incrementing indexes, i.e.

```
input = [0, 1, 2, ..., 124, 125, 126, 127, -128, -127,... -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...]
```

And after encoding the message in the QRCode and decoding it on the responder side, I obtain the following byte array output:

```
output = [0, 1, 2, ..., 124, 125, 126, 127, 63, 63,... 63, 63, 63, 0, 1, 2, ...]
```

All the "negative" byte values are turned to ASCII char 63: '?' question mark characters.
I assume that something is going wrong with the encoding charset, but since I am using ISO-8859-1 which everyone claims to be the solution of such kind of issue ([other topic treating the same kind of issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489611/1424133) or [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=103)), I don't see where is my mistake, or if I am skipping a step during the instanciation of the encoding or the decoding.
Here is the code that I execute to encode a given byte array:

```java
String text = "";
byte[] res = new byte[272];
for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    res[i] = (byte) (i%256);
}
try {
    text = new String(res, "ISO8859_1");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO
}
Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Encode.ACTION);
Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.TYPE, Contents.Type.TEXT);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.FORMAT, "ISO8859_1");
intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA, text);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.FORMAT, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString());

boolean useVCard = intent.getBooleanExtra(USE_VCARD_KEY, false);
QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder(activity, intent, dimension, useVCard);
Bitmap bitmap = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
```

And to decode a QRCode, I send the following Intent

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.qrcodeDecoding);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Scan.ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.MODE, Intents.Scan.QR_CODE_MODE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

And wait for Result:

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent data)
{
    if(request == 0)
    {
        //action
        if(result == RESULT_OK)
        {
            String res = data.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT);
            byte[] dat = null;

            try{
                    dat = res.getBytes("ISO8859_1");
            } catch(UnsopportedEncodingException e) {
                    //TODO
            }
        }
        else if(result == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            //TODO
        }
    }

}
```

Could you please tell me where are my mistakes, or where should I look at?

Thank you a lot,

Franck

Comment: Just to "play around" (I have no idea about this) what happens if you use UTF-8 as encoding for example?

Comment: UTF-8 certainly won't work. Not every byte sequence is a valid UTF-8 sequence, to start. So it's not even possible to get a string out of most inputs that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the mistake of thinking that you can turn arbitrary binary data into a valid string without using some kind of armouring.  It doesn't work.  Binary -> text -> binary is lossy using any of the standard character sets / encoding.  (Hint: using UTF-8 won't work either.)

You should use something like base64 encoding or hexadecimal encoding to ensure that the binary data doesn't get mangled.

Comment: I agree with the overall sentiment; ISO-8559-1 does happen to work for this purpose in Java though.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you a lot, using base64 encoding in my implementation solved the problem!

Comment: @SeanOwen I agree with you, encoding and decoding byte[] to String ISO-8859-1 and vice-versa works. The problem may be located on the ZXing layer. However, base64 solved the case.

Comment: It is my understanding ISO-8859-1 is 100% efficient when converting an arbitrary buffer to a string. base64 is 75%. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: @LucaCarlon - No it isn't.  But efficiency isn't the only issue.

Comment: @StephenC if by no you mean I'm not wrong, then do you consider binary -> ISO-8859-1 lossy? Do you see any reason for not doing it?

Comment: Yes, I do.  At least in general, if not in this particular case.   Binary data represented as an ISO-8859-1 "text" is fragile in a lot of contexts.

Comment: @SeanOwen I hit the same problem, wasted 2 days already. I have a random byte array, converting it to ISO-8859-1 string and passing to qr code writer didn't solve my problem. Converting to base64 does solve it but then it increases the total data size. What can I do next?

Answer (score 5):

In one of my apps I needed to encode and decode a bytes array in a QRCode generated with the ZXing app. As the byte array contained compressed text data I wanted to avoid base64 encoding. It is possible to do this but as I have so far not seen a complete set of code snippets I will post them here.

Encoding:

```
public void showQRCode(Activity activity, byte[] data){
  Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
  intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "TEXT_TYPE");
  intent.putExtra("ENCODE_SHOW_CONTENTS", false);
  intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", new String(data, "ISO-8859-1"));
  activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Start scanning:

```
public static void startQRCodeScan(Activity activity){
  Intent intent = new Intent(com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN);
  intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
  intent.putExtra("CHARACTER_SET", "ISO-8859-1");
  activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Scan result handler:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  byte[] result = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT").getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
  ...
}
```

I think not setting CHARACTER_SET to ISO-8859-1 in the intent data for starting the scan is the point that made the code of the original question fail. It took me quite some time to dig this out as I have not seen this clearly posted anywhere and Latin 1 encoding is the standard encoding for QR code in Xzing. Especially tricky is the fact that the Xzing online decoder http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx does not set CHARACTER_SET as well so that the generated QR code looks faulty when decoded on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, QR codes encode text, not bytes. Inside of course they translate input to a series of bytes, though that's opaque to the caller. You are right that, as it happens, choosing the right encoding would let you sneak the bytes through, and ISO-8859-1 is the right choice here. It does work, actually.

ASCII is not possible since it does not define chars for >= 128, and UTF-8 is definitely not going to work

The issue here is probably your code. I am not sure what you're attempting here... it looks like you're setting up to send an `Intent` somewhere (to Barcode Scanner?) but then you don't, you're just making an `Intent` and sending it to some code you copied from the project? I imagine something's gone wrong with how you are setting extras to the `Intent`.

This should be much simpler if you're doing it within your app. Just reuse `QRCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap()` directly and delete the rest of this.

Comment: The only constructor of `QRCodeEncoder` takes for arguments `QRCodeEncoder(Activity activity, Intent intent, int dimension, boolean useVCard)`. And since there are no setter methods, it appread to me that it was the only way to go. If you could be a bit more specific about what could "go wrong" with the extras? It seems that base64 encoding and passing then an ISO8859-1 String to the `QRCodeEncoder` made the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I mean that you don't need the class at all -- just copy the method I indicated. The code in `android/` is not intended as a library; it's our app. The main problem is that you are doing something superfluous here -- listening for an `Intent` when you didn't send one to reply to. Read the javadoc for the keys -- `FORMAT` is nothing do with character encoding and you set it twice.