# ZXing.Net Encode string to QR Code in CF

Tags: c#, compact-framework, zxing

How could I encode my string into a QR Code using [ZXing.Net](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com)?

I can already decode, but having problems in encoding. It has an error that says: *no encoder available for format AZTEC*.

Here is my code:

```
IBarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter();
Bitmap barcodeBitmap;
var result = writer.Encode("Hello").ToBitmap();
barcodeBitmap = new Bitmap(result);
pictureBox1.Image = barcodeBitmap;
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't fully initialize the BarcodeWriter. You have to set the barcode format.

Try the following code snippet:

```
IBarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter { Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE };
var result = writer.Write("Hello");
var barcodeBitmap = new Bitmap(result);
pictureBox1.Image = barcodeBitmap;
```

Comment: I added encoding functionality to the WindowsCE demo which you can find in the source code repository of ZXing.Net.
I posted a more complete list of necessary steps in the forum
http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/discussions/396017

Comment: Im not getting the .Format property on mine. But the one you posted on CodePlex did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@dizzytri99er

Seems that I have sucessfully encoded a message with ZXing.net therefore I think it does support Aztec encoding

This is the code I have used;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IBarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter
            {
                Format = BarcodeFormat.AZTEC
            };
        Bitmap aztecBitmap;
        var result = writer.Write("I love you ;)");
        aztecBitmap = new Bitmap(result);

        using (var stream = new FileStream("test.bmp", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            var aztecAsBytes = ImageToByte(aztecBitmap);
            stream.Write(aztecAsBytes, 0, aztecAsBytes.Length);
        }
    }


    public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
    }
```

Comment: AZTEC is supported since version 0.11 from March 2013

Answer (score 0):

could it possibly be the size of the codes your are scanning?

take a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=1260)

best way to generate and encode QR codes would be...

[QR code encoder](https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C) and [Zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/)

Comment: Nope. I dont think so. I am done with the scanning part. Im now trying to produce a QR Code from a string.

Comment: after some reading, im pretty sure that Zxing does not support Aztec encoding.... only decoding im afraid. [QR code encoder](https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C) is the best QR code generator and [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/) is a great framework for encoding and decoding, may be a hassle switching over but worth it in the long run if you can get the QR code

Comment: are you sure about that? but I am not trying to encode in Aztec.

Comment: if the error message mentions aztec then i can only assume that you are. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489048/qr-code-encoding-and-decoding-using-zxing) discussion talks about getting Zxing to encode QR codes but i honestly think you are better off with QR code encoder and Zbar

Comment: But I dont think Zbar has an encoder/decoder for the .NET Compact Framework.

Comment: then im at a loss im afraid dude. I dont see any reason why it wouldn't be compatible but from personal experience Zbar and QR code have served me well