# Generated barcode datamatrix on Android

Tags: android

I have to make an app that takes strings and makes barcodes in Datamatrix formats.
I found Barcode4j. Looks like a library that fits my needs, but I can't us it on Android.
somebody can tell me how can i us it or tell me wich free library works on Android(please Datamatrix format)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/ It runs on android and is some sort of standard for barcodes.

Comment: yes, there is a issue going on. read here: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=572 have a closer look to the .diff from guillaum. Hope it helps.

Comment: if it had helped, it should go like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489048/qr-code-encoding-and-decoding-using-zxing

Answer (score 1):

The [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) project supports the datamatrix format, among many others.

Comment: i need to generated a barcode datamatrix not read or scanner.