# Decode byte[] to a String in Android using zxing

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I'm trying to replace a small bit of functionality that's currently handled by the outdated Zbar library. I'm basically capturing a preview frame using Android's Camera.PreviewCallback and processing the byte[] data into a string. Looking at the ZXing implementation of this from online examples, I'm having a hard time believing that the data needs to go through that many custom objects in order to translate a simple QR byte array to a string. Example: [QR Code encoding and decoding using zxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489048/qr-code-encoding-and-decoding-using-zxing?rq=1)
.

Does anybody have a clean solution for this? I'd even be happy with just an explanation of what Zxing is doing (and why).

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Consider something like this?

`symData = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this solution did not work.